# Android, Robotium - Issue taking screenshot

Tags: android, robotium

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my Android application using Robotium, I'm using the below function that I found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/robotium-developers/browse_thread/thread/c5cf28ef88918d7d).

```
public static String SCREEN_SHOTS_LOCATION="/sdcard/"; 

public static void takeScreenShot(View view, String name) throws Exception 
{ 
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
    view.buildDrawingCache(); 
    Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache(); 
    FileOutputStream fos = null; 

    try 
    { 
         File sddir = new File(SCREEN_SHOTS_LOCATION); 

         if (!sddir.exists()) 
         { 
             sddir.mkdirs(); 
         } 
         fos = new FileOutputStream(SCREEN_SHOTS_LOCATION + name + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"); 

         if (fos != null) 
         { 
             b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos); 
             fos.close(); 
         } 
     } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     { 
     } 
}
```

I'm calling it like this from my test:

```
takeScreenShot(solo.getView(0), "Test");
```

When I call the function, I get a NullPointerException on that line, it looks to me as if the View is null.

I've also tried using

> solo.getViews();

and cycling through each view and taking a screenshot, but I get a NullPointerException for each also.

```
ArrayList views = solo.getViews();

for(int i=0; i < views.size(); i++)
{
    takeScreenShot(solo.getView(i), "Test");
}
```

I'm new enough to Android & Android test automation using Robotium, can anybody give me some advice on debugging this, or the reason why Views seem to be null and my screen captures don't work?

TIA.

Update

```
Error in testUI:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.myapp.test.UITests.testUI(UITests.java:117)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
        at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
        at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
        at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are getting NullPointerException is because you are using getView(int id) incorrectly. As you are giving it an index instead of id, it will not find the view that you are looking for and thus returns null. What you want to use is following:

takeScreenShot(solo.getViews().get(0), "Test")

Which means the first view of all the views available to Robotium at a given time.

Comment: I've tried it this way also, but I still see the NullPointerException on the line where I call takeScreenShot. Any other way I can determine if my View is present?

Comment: What do you get if you do a solo.getViews().size()?

Comment: Ok. What exactly does the log say, would it be possible for you to paste it?

Comment: I've added the stack trace, it occurs on the line where takeScreenShot is called.

Comment: Weird - If i copy the contents of takeScreenShot into my test class instead of the call to the function, it works! I only get the NullPointerException when I try to call the function?

Comment: Also, if I copy the takeScreenShot function into my test class and then call it, it works fine. I had the takeScreenShot function in a JAR I was referencing in my test project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your emulator has some megabytes set aside for the SD card.

If you want to pull the jpg back to your PC, you can get java to run this command line:

> C:\Users\Me\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe pull
>   /sdcard/test_1329402481933.jpg c:\

Answer (score 0):

For taking screen shot at any point of the application Just write this piece of code

solo.takeScreenshot();

But don't forget to give permission in your main Application.