# Is it possible to name a screenshot taken with robotium?

Tags: java, testing, automation, robotium

I'm using android to do some testing, and would like to give the screen shots a name other than the time they were taken. Looking at the code, there is a method that can be used to do this by passing a `String name` into the method, but when I try to do this, I get an error. Does anyone know why this might be?

This is the method I use:

`solo.takeScreenshot("FileName");`

or:

```
String fileName = "FileName";
solo.takeScreenshot(filename);
```

Neither work. Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the javadocs here: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/detail?name=robotium-solo-3.3-javadoc.jar

I do not see any takeScreenshot() methods that take arguments. So, without knowing more about what version you are using and what error you are running into, I am not sure I can help.

However, if you want to extend the `Solo` class to add the method you want, try looking at this question: [Android, Robotium - Issue taking screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819542/android-robotium-issue-taking-screenshot)

Comment: The method was added a few days ago, and I've downloaded the code and tried to recompile the .jar file, but not having any luck. Maybe I should rephrase the question. Here is the method:https://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.java

it is the last method