# How to create screenshot in Robotium

Tags: android, android-studio, robotium

I'd like to know how can I take screenshot on AVD in Robotium. I have read that 1st I have to have permissions but I've already done this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But still I have error on Android Monitor

```
D/Robotium: Can't save the screenshot! Requires write permission (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in AndroidManifest.xml of the application under test.
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Screenshot/asd.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I created manually directory to be sure that dir exist.

Also I was trying to take screenshot on my disk

```
String path = "/sdcard/SS";
solo.getConfig().screenshotSavePath = path;
solo.takeScreenshot("asd");

path = "C:/";
solo.getConfig().screenshotSavePath = path;
solo.takeScreenshot("asd");
```

but error still exist. What's wrong with taking screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android, Robotium - Issue taking screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819542/android-robotium-issue-taking-screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already created the SS dir:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SS";
```

Comment: You cannot point the sdcard's root dir like this: "/sdcard". You have to get the storage dir via system's Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() because the sdcard's mounting point could be different on the different devices. 
So it could probably help you with this permission error.

Comment: It's still not working - same errors. Path with this code is /storage/emulated/0 but it's link to /sdcard/

Comment: @k.szulc, another thing you could do - check if sdcard is enabled on the emulator? Or the space of the emulated sdcard is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create your path, as @Seishin said:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/SS";
```

Then, go to your `build.gradle` file and downgrade `targetSdkVersion` to `22`.

Higher than `22`, I mean: `23` or `24`, requires to define Android Permissions Control, which is a bit different than defining only:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Read: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

These kind of permissions (runtime permissions) work on Android 6.0 and higher version and the needed code looks like:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

To avoid it, just downgrade your `targetSdkVersion`.

Hope it will help

Comment: I set path like you said, in my build.gradle there is only `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` and both are now at version 22. And it's not working at all. I see that my AndroidManifest.xml is weird, because of `<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="LauncherActivity">` It says that LauncherActivity cannot be resolved. Also in `<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" android:targetPackage="appPackage"/>` . Anyway it's not high priority to take ss, but it's weird working.

Comment: which android version do you have on device?

Comment: it's 6.0 (23API) but I have also tried on 5.1 (22API)